# Get traffic incident data from 'here' with free public basic plan

Tags: key, here-api, traffic

I try to get traffic data for (example) the A4 between Wenden,- and Engelskirchen, Germany. I am using this link scheme:

```
https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.1/incidents.xml?bbox=50.98690,7.40913;50.96840,7.87189&app_id={MY_FREE_API_PLAN_APP_ID}&app_code={MY_FREE_API_PLAN_APP_CODE}
```

But the xml which I get says only:

```
<Error_Message><Error>This is not a valid app_id and app_code pair.
Please verify that the values are not swapped between the app_id and
app_code and the values provisioned by HERE (either by your customer
representative or via http://developer.here.com/myapps) were copied
correctly into the request.</Error><Error_description>NA</Error_description>
</Error_Message>
```

The APP_ID and APP_CODE are 100% right. I want to use this data for home / there's no commercial use planed at this point.

Is there an mistake in my request for the data or want 'here' tell me on this way that I have to buy for the data?

API Plan Overview: https://developer.here.com/plans
Link build on this example: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/traffic/topics/request-constructing.html

Answer (score 0):

On a hunch I tried using curly braces `{ }` around the app_id and app_code in a request to the routing API (because I do not have credentials for the traffic API) and got a similar response. So, if you are using curly braces around your app_id and app_code, remove them.

For example, this fails:

[https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/getlinkinfo.xml?waypoint=43.066628,-71.471729&app_id={DemoAppId01082013GAL}&app_code={AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg}&linkattributes=all](https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/getlinkinfo.xml?waypoint=43.066628,-71.471729&app_id=%7BDemoAppId01082013GAL%7D&app_code=%7BAJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg%7D&linkattributes=all)

and this works:

https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/getlinkinfo.xml?waypoint=43.066628,-71.471729&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&linkattributes=all